# static transform shrinking and expanding randomly

Tags: rviz, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Video link: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3743872/StaticTransformScalingIssueRviz.ogv

Transform /map to /base_footprint is a 2d transform consisting of only position x and y, and orientation z and w. Transform /base_footprint to /asdf is constant and only consists of a shift in z of 1.5. This suggests the transform from /map to /asdf should always have a z component of exactly 1.5, but the transform lookup seems to scale randomly. Also all transforms relative to /base_footprint scale the same amount as shown in the video.

I have also seen this behaviour outside of rviz when calling tf::TransformListener::lookupTransform().

Has anyone else observed this behavior?

What could be causing this, and how can it be fixed?

This recording is Indigo with Gazebo, but I have seen this behavior in Hydro and Indigo, Gazebo and real-time.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187577/static-transform-shrinking-and-expanding-randomly/) by [kmhallen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3102/kmhallen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1416 on 2014-07-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The custom Kalman filter node that generated the transform from /map to /base_footprint did not normalize the quaternion representing orientation at each step. The tf library must assume the quaternion is normalized, and propagate the error through the tf tree. Normalizing fixed the issue completely.

The position jitter in this case comes from a noisy position estimate, not multiple publishing.

---

Originally posted by [kmhallen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3102/kmhallen/) with karma: 1416 on 2014-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My experience is that when tf frames appear to flip around randomly the most common case is that there are 2 tf broadcasters to the same link....

I'd first check the tf chain does not contain double broadcasted links using tf_monitor (http://wiki.ros.org/tf#tf_monitor)..

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-07-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-07-24**:
Also you can debug using roswtf which has a tf plugin which detects that.